# Securely installing software in a hostile environment

Tags: man-in-the-middle, apt

Consider the case where a user with a freshly installed Linux box is operating in a hostile environment controlled by an attacker with access to the internet gateway.

How can such a user update the system and install software securely using the available package manager, e.g., apt, npm, pacman, etc, when they are targeted by an attacker who can use mitm, dns spoofing, arp cache poisoning?

Is trusting the package manager's signature enough?

Comment: what kind of mitm are we talking?deep packet inspection?can the attacker break https?does the attacker have a malware running in the victim pc?

Comment: @yeah_well I am concerned with using apt securely and AFAIK, repositories mostly don't use https anyway. The question specifiies the system being freshly installed Linux boc.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/why-there-is-no-https-transport-for-debian-apt-tool

Comment: @yeah_well. I see, but the answer, as well, as in many otehr similar questions I have read on the topic, suggests installing some software. My concern is about downloading the software securely in a environment controlled by an attacker in the first place.

Comment: Debian package distribution already includes a mechanism to verify packages: all packages are signed with Gpg. If an active man-in-the-middle redirects your traffic to a server with corrupted packages, the corruption will be detected because the GPG signatures won't be valid

Comment: The apt doesn't use https because there is inbuilt check that doesn't allow mitm

Comment: its in the question i posted,take your time and read all the answers not just the top one

Comment: @yeah_well Where do the GPG signatures, especially for the newer packages, come from? If they have to be downloaded too, can't an attacker perform DNS spoofing and redirect my requests to his server where he can serve up malicious versions of the software along with its "correct" signature which apt will then use to verify the download?

Answer (score 1):

> Is trusting the package manager's signature enough?

No. There have been numerous vulnerabilities for those in the past. Of course it also depends on the adversary. But when you assume that he can do mitm then he probably is well equipped and can do some other attacks too.
Just because it has been signed somehow it does not automatically make it bullet prove. In the end it is software checking other software. (Most) Software has bugs ... Maybe someone got the signing key and can now sign anything they want ...
iirc there have been bugs in the update mechanism for the BIOS in case of big companies with big budgets too (Intel)

Originally apt did not use https and there even was a website explaining specifically why. After a new attack was published which would have been prevented by https the owner of the website changed its content. Sadly the original site does not exist anymore.
https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/aidxwa/why_does_apt_not_use_https/

When you google for packet manager security + linux you should find some more or less recent publications and potential attacks.

Using apt with https makes it certainly harder. The question is if it is hard enough. Against a nation state which could fake certs, redirect traffic or has access to the server itself it wont help.
You could take a look at the certs send by the server or watch the system behavior. Ideally, you would still have another secure(TM) system where you could cross check the results.

Comment: Thats like saying dont use operating system because every once in a while there is an RCE.Zero day doesn't count man.

Answer (score 1):

Distribution package managers verify the integrity of package information and downloaded packages using cryptographic signatures. If any package data is tampered with on the server or during transit, you will receive an error, and the install will not complete. As a result, an active man-in-the-middle cannot modify your package data.

There is one class of attack against this model that does not rely on a software vulnerability, involving re-sending the victim valid and signed information about packages, but from a previous version that may not include the latest security patches, if the victim hadn't yet received the latest version. This would allow the attacker to delay updates without the victim noticing, although some package managers may avoid this by distrusting the information after days/weeks. This type of attack could be mitigated from a man-in-the-middle by using TLS. However, if an attacker really wants to deny updates, even if noticeably so, they could just block your traffic altogether.

TLS may have some other marginally useful benefits, such as confidentiality of which packages you are installing (from an active adjacent attacker, at least). Additionally, since no data can be modified in transit, it likely lowers the attack surface in the package manager that is reachable by the attacker in case there is a zero day. That said, TLS is between you and the mirrors, not you and who publishes the packages. Many mirrors are run by third-parties; a malicious or compromised mirror would negate any of the aforementioned benefits.

If you want to use TLS, you can install the `apt-transport-https` package on Debian-based distributions, and change your mirrors to use HTTPS. Others may have similar packages or configuration options. Note that the utility of this is dependant on the repositories actually serving packages over HTTPS; I'm not sure of the prevalence of this support across both official or 3rd-party repositories.

**TL;DR: Most likely yes; package managers are generally designed to be secure in an untrusted network scenario, although they are not without their occasional vulnerabilities (like all software).**

Comment: Does this mean that, in order to download `apt-transport-https` in the first place, I'll have to just trust the package signing to secure the download, at least for the first one?

Comment: @user942937 it may depend if your particular distribution ships with it installed or not, but that's correct if not installed. Keep in mind as mentioned, package signing alone is sufficient for installing a package safely.